# (Jackson) How to deserialize a wrapped array?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

Currently, I'm receiving this JSON input, which I have no control whatsoever:

```
{
    "A" : {
        "B" : {
            "B" : [{
                    "Whatever" : "String",
                    "Number": 123
                }
            ],
            "SiblingObject" : true
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to deserialize the B array that's inside the B object directly into the A class without having to create another extra class to wrap the B object. Something like this:

```
public class A {

    private List<B> bList;

    public List<B> getB() {
        return bList;
    }

    @JsonProperty("B")
    public void setB(List<B> bList) {
        this.bList = bList;
    }
}
```

I've tried doing

```
public class A {

    private List<B> bList;

    public List<B> getB() {
        return bList;
    }

    @JsonProperty("B")
    public void setB(Map<String, Object> bList) {
        this.bList = (List<B>) bList.get("B");
    }
}
```

but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: The simplest solution I can think of would be to go ahead and create the wrapper class but then by using field based annotations and ignored getter/setters I would have the public API the same as what you want.  Another option would be to use a custom JsonDeserializer but that seems like a lot of work for tackling this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way of doing it. However, it will require traversing the input JSON twice.

In first pass, you create the normal A instance without the List.
In second pass, you use Jackson's node traversal to reach the correct B object and parse from there.

See the code below:

```
public class WrapperJsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("wrapper.json");
        A a = null;
        try {
            a = om.readValue(in, A.class);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("wrapper.json");
        try {
            JsonNode node = om.readValue(in, JsonNode.class).get("B").get("B");
            JsonParser parser = node.traverse();
            List<B> bList = om.readValue(parser, List.class);
            a.setB(bList);
            System.out.println(a.isSibling());
            System.out.println(a.getB());
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties
    public static class A {

        @JsonIgnore
        private List<B> bList;
        private boolean sibling;

        public List<B> getB() {
            return bList;
        }

        public void setB(List<B> bList) {
            this.bList = bList;
        }

        public boolean isSibling() {
            return sibling;
        }

        public void setSibling(boolean sibling) {
            this.sibling = sibling;
        }
    }

    public static class B {

        private String whatever;

        public String getWhatever() {
            return whatever;
        }

        public void setWhatever(String whatever) {
            this.whatever = whatever;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return whatever;
        }

    }

}
```